# Use strong induction to prove number of vertices on complete tree is $2l-1$

Tags: induction, trees, binary

Can someone help me construct this proof using strong induction?

> Use strong induction on $l$ to show that for all $l \geq 1$, a full
>   binary tree with $l$ leaves has $2l-1$ vertices total.

Comment: Establish a basis. $l=1$ is a complete binary tree isomorphic to $K_1$ which has $2(1)-1=1$ vertices.

Comment: So what do we do after we get the inductive hypothesis of p(k) = 2k-1 and try to prove p(k+1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Strong" induction is really not needed here.  For the inductive step, just pick any pair of leaves with the same parent and consider the tree obtained by removing them both; it has $l - 1$ leaves and you can proceed by "weak" induction.  I imagine the proof you're "supposed" to write involves splitting your tree at its root and obtaining two trees of $k$ and $m$ leaves, where $m + k = l$; the sum of their numbers of vertices is one short of the correct number since you removed the original root.

Answer (score 0):

Establish a basis: $l=1$ is a full binary tree isomorphic to $K_1$ which has $2(1)-1=1$ vertices.

Induction Hypothesis: Fix a $k$ and assume for all $l<k$ we have $2l-1$ vertices on a full binary tree with $l$ leaves.

Induction: Now consider the case when $l=k$. Suppose I have a graph $G$ that is a full binary tree with $k$ leaves. What happens when we delete two leaf vertices, say $u$ and $v$, that share a common internal vertex? Can we apply the induction hypothesis on $G-u-v$? If so, what happens when we add the two leaf vertices back in and reform $G$?

Comment: Shouldn't you have a step that says P(k+1) = 2(k+1)-1? So that P(k+1) = 2k+2-1 -> P(k)+2.

Comment: A full binary tree is when each vertex is either a leaf or an internal vertex with exactly two leaves, right? It is not clear to me why strong induction is necessary as I only have to delete two leaves with a common vertex to create a smaller order full binary tree. If the the binary tree were complete, then we would have to delete an entire level of leaves. This would require strong induction as we are never entirely sure how many leaves are in a complete binary tree's final level.

Comment: It is just a part of my assignment to use strong induction, and I would agree that without it the solution is intuitively more simple and easy to understand. However, for the purposes of the exercise, can you show how it's done with induction?

Comment: @user3064097: The second argument sketched in Ryan Reich’s answer uses strong induction.